# AutoLayout for modal ViewController is distorted when entering text in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout

I have Viewcontroller with AutoLayout for its views and subviews 
I added it as a Modal view controller

It starts fitting well as in image

[image]

but After textField starts edits it changes to 
[image]

I tried to add

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        return true
    }
```

it works well when he starts editing but distorts again when user dismiss keyboard

Comment: I don't think there's enough here for me to help.  Have you used the View Debugger when the problem occurs to see what constraint are being used?

Comment: I am getting same issue. You got any solution for it ?

Comment: I used Navigation controller instead and did not try it again but since then I improved in Autolayout so much I will try again and report the answer